# $r(l)$ denote the reflection in a line $l$, and $u\in\mathbb{E}$ be any point in a euclidean space

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

$r(l)$ denote the reflection in a line $l$, and $u\in\mathbb{E}$ be any point in a euclideian space, we need to prove $r(l)^u=r(lu)$ where $lu$ is the image of $l$ under $u$

Hints: all points C in the plane equidistant from two given point A and B lie on a line $l$, called perpendicular bisector A and B, any isometry of the plane maps line to line.

thanks for helping. I have no clue to solve this

Comment: What is "the image of $l$ under $u$"?

Comment: As @Aretino has asked, what is the image of a line under a point ? Moreover, how can we understand cryptic formula: $r(l)^u=r(lu)$: what, in particular, means the exponent notation ? Doing $u$ times $r(l)$ ??? Certainly not...

Comment: Please use... usual notations.